# The definition of "tailor-made"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

[Merriam Webster's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tailor-made) of **tailor-made** comes very counterintuitive:

> factory made rather than hand-rolled

Shouldn't it be the other way around? All other dictionaries I have consulted, even other definitions on MW, contradict this definition. The ODO for example defines the word as *Made, adapted, or suited for a particular purpose or person.* Then how could it be factory made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of the definition there (the third listed on the site) is specific to cigarettes, as shown in the example that they give. This is why "hand-rolled" is also used in the definition. Hand-rolling is not a general term that can apply to all product creation techniques.

Comment: So you are saying in a cigarette-specific context, the meaning is the opposite of other usages of the word?

Comment: Yes, that's the case. It's a narrow definition.

Comment: That makes sense. Some sources to back it up would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't know if I have a better source than a dictionary... but here's of an example of tailor-made being used as the opposite of hand-rolled https://www.nhs.uk/news/heart-and-lungs/roll-ups-as-hazardous-as-factory-made-cigarettes/ If you google, you'll see "straights" and "tailor-mades" used for the opposite of the hand-rolled cigarettes. These are colloquial so they may not be used by many official sources.

Comment: Here's a second source for the cigarette sense : https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tailor-made - slang A cigarette that is machine-made, rather than hand-rolled. *Don't you have any tailor-made smokes?*

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=abYBCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT18705&dq=tailor-made+cigarette&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis6NOwlo_bAhUFfpAKHXHBB4kQ6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=tailor-made%20cigarette&f=false